# how do i get an output of the current date spelled out in C using time.h or is there another way?

Tags: c

I'm quite new, What I'm aiming for is something like:
Saturday, January 29, 2022
and this is what I currently have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>
#include <time.h>



int main(void) {
  time_t currentTime;
  time(&currentTime);

  printf("%s\n", ctime(&currentTime));  
 


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check this one [strftime](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/strftime)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`localtime`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/localtime) and [`strftime`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/strftime).

Example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    time_t currentTime;
    char result[64];

    time(&currentTime);
    size_t len = strftime(result, sizeof result, "%A, %B %d, %Y",
                          localtime(&currentTime));
    if(len != 0)
        printf("result = %s\n", result);

    printf("length of result = %zu\n", len);
}
```

Possible output:

```
result = Saturday, January 29, 2022
length of result = 26
```